# Azure Push Notification and APNS between two phones

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, azure

When I look up examples of Push Notifications I see examples of one notification being sent to many users. Like weather alerts for instance.
Are there any examples of one to one? Like a turn based game with two players. Is it done the same way as one to many where you would create a topic like "phoneA_Id + phoneB_Id" for each one to one relationship? It seems like you would have millions of topics that are short lived.
I am just verifying that is the correct way to do it. It would be great to see a simple example of this with azure push notifications using apns.